# Trouble showing that quotient of solvable group is solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

As the title suggests, I'm trying to demonstrate that a quotient of a solvable group is solvable. What I have so far is this:

Let $G$ be a solvable group with normal series $N_{0} \trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq N_{\ell}$, where $N_{k} / N_{k - 1}$ is abelian for $k = 1, \ldots, \ell$. Moreover, let $K \trianglelefteq G$. Then the sequence $M_{k} = N_{k} K / K$ is a normal series for $G / K,$ and $M_{k} / M_{k - 1} \cong N_{k} K / N_{k - 1}K$. We need to show that $M_{k} / M_{k - 1}$ is abelian, but I've no clue how to go about it. My first intuition was to say that if $x, y \in N_{k} K$, then $(xy) N_{k - 1} K = (yx) N_{k - 1} K$ iff $(xy)^{-1} (yx) \in N_{k - 1}K$, and try to show this expression is in $N_{k - 1} K$ by adding in expressions of the form $(g g^{-1})$ as appropriate to get the right parts to cancel, but I'm skeptical that this is the right way to go about it because I cannot see how to apply the fact that $N_{k} / N_{k - 1}$ is abelian, which I would imagine is pretty central to the claim. I also don't see an obvious way to make convenient cancellations because both $x$ and $y$ are elements of $N_{k} K$, which I don't really see how to collapse into elements of $N_{k - 1}K$.

I'm pretty thoroughly stuck, and this is the last part of the problem I need to figure out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By the Second Isomorphism Theorem $N_kK/N_{k-1}K \cong N_k/(N_k \cap N_{k-1}K)$ which is abelian because (by the Third Isomorphism Theorem) it is isomorphic to a quotient group of the abelian group $N_k/N_{k-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plan:

1. Let's fix an index $i$. Because $K\unlhd G$, we know that $N_iK=\{nk\mid n\in N_i, k\in K\}$ for all $i$.
2. Consider the mapping $f:N_i\to N_iK/N_{i-1}K$ defined by $f(n)=nN_{i-1}K$ that maps an element $n\in N_i$ to its coset modulo $N_{i-1}K$. Verify that this is a homomorphism of groups.
3. Show that the homomorphism $f$ in the previous step is surjective.
4. Show that $N_{i-1}\subseteq \operatorname{ker} f$.
5. Show that we also have a surjective homomorphism (induced by $f$) $$N_i/N_{i-1}\to N_iK/N_{i-1}K.$$
6. Why does step 5 imply that $N_iK/N_{i-1}K$ is abelian?

Comment: I follow steps 1 and 2, can believe step 3 (could probably work out the details on my own), and I'm down with step 4 (it's apparent that $f(N_{i}) = \{ N_{i - 1} K \}$). Step 5 would obviously imply that $N_{i} K / N_{i - 1} K$ is abelian (you can't map an abelian group homomorphically onto a non-abelian), but I'm not sure how I'd induce $f$. I see how I'd do it if $N_{i - 1} = \ker f$, but this one is not clear.

Comment: @AJY: It is not necessarily true that $N_{i-1}=\operatorname{ker} f$. For all we know we might have $K=N_i$ when $f$ is the trivial homomorphism. But,  if $H$ and $K$ are both normal subgroups of $G$, and also $H\le K$, then we have a surjective homomorphism $p:G/H\to G/K$ given by $p(gH)=gK$. So here we have the well-defined homomorphisms
$$N_i/N_{i-1}\to N_i/\operatorname{ker} f\to N_iK/N_{i-1}K.$$ Both are surjective.

Comment: Indeed it's not necessarily true, which was my issue. But I think I see now the solution. The map $N_{i} / N_{i - 1}$ is the surjective map $x N_{i} \mapsto x \ker f$, and the map $N_{i} / \ker f \to N_{i} K / N_{i - 1} K$ is the obvious isomorphism promised by the first isomorphism theorem (promised by virtue of $f$ being a surjection). Taken together, we have a surjective homomorphism $N_{i} / N_{i - 1} \to N_{i} K / N_{i - 1} K$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup! You nailed it @AJY !